# jsf calling bean method from javascript using p:remoteCommand

Tags: javascript, jsf, google-maps-api-3, primefaces, remotecommand

I cant trigger a bean method from my javascript.

the myRemote() should be calling the primefaces remoteCommand in the xhtml which should be triggering a call to test1() in the bean, but this is NEVER executing.  WHY?

And the alert does get displayed so it is hitting the addListener in the javascript

my javascript

```
function loadMarkers(m) {

    for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        PF('w_gmap').addOverlay(m[i]);

        //add listener for event clicking on marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(m[i], 'click', function () {  

            myRemote();  //should be handled by p:remoteCommand
            alert("HI 123");
        }); 
    }   
}
```

xhtml

```
<h:form styleClass="simpleformstyle" id="remoteForm">
    <p:remoteCommand name="myRemote" actionListener="#{mapBean.test1}" process="@this"/>
</h:form>
```

bean method called from p:remoteCommand

```
public void test1(){
    System.out.println("HIIIIIIIIIIII");
}
```

So when i click on a marker, the click event triggers and the myRemote() should be called which the xhtml handles and then should be calling the bean method.  And the alert is displayed so it is hitting the addListener in the javascript

Comment: Do you see myRemote() called?

Comment: Could you try actionListener insteadof action? Let us know

Comment: Uhm ... Could you turn Developer Tools and see if XMLHttpRequest sent and see Request/Response Header/Body Error Return code ...?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

immediate="true" solved my issue, everything behaves as expected

```
<h:form styleClass="simpleformstyle" id="remoteForm">
    <p:remoteCommand name="myRemote" actionListener="#{mapBean.test1}" process="@this"  immediate="true"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this solved the problem? I never needed to use immediate on a remote command.

Comment: Indeed. This is most likely a workaroundfor a different non-visible problem